# CesiumJS: How can I draw an arrow head at both ends of a polyline?

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

The sandcastle produces:

[image: line with arrow head]

How can I control the size of the arrow head being drawn?

How can I get an arrow head on the other end of the polyline pointed in the opposite direction?

Comment: In the future, please place separate questions in separate posts on this site.  Stack Overflow is intended to be a one-question-per-post site, with ranked answers per question.

Answer (score 1):

The thickest part of the arrowhead must fit in the width given for rendering the polyline.  In this Sandcastle, you've got `width: 3` which will give a very thin arrowhead.  Try `width: 13` or some other numbers, to get better results.

[image: screenshot with two arrows]

Currently there is no support for double-arrow lines.  I suppose you could pick a midpoint of the line, and draw two separate lines emanating from that midpoint, to get arrows on both sides.  Be careful that the midpoint you select must be along the great arc between the endpoints, not just the average of the lat/lon values.

Here's a [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) where I made a double arrow using a pair of North-South lines.  I'm cheating a bit since the great arc is the same as the lat/lon midpoint in the case of North-South, but you won't have this easy of a time going East-West.  Still this demonstrates the idea.